# Android hardware latency time

Tags: android

Can I measure the time between android code execution and hardware responding?
Like, if the code " bluetooth writing" executes, how long will it take the bluetooth hardware responds?

I am using the bluetooth hardware on my cellphone to communicate with a BLE device(peripheral) of a beacon. Also, I want to use my phone to generate a single frequency tone. Generally, I want know a way that I can measure the time between the CODE and the HARDWARE responding on my cellphone. Maybe phonegap using javascript is not time accurate, so I will switch to Java based native app later.

Below is part of the code, it's part of the BLE.java which serves as plugins of the phonegap app.

```
@Override
    public void onDescriptorReadRequest(
        BluetoothDevice device,
        int requestId,
        int offset,
        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor)
    {
        System.out.println("onDescriptorReadRequest("+device.getAddress()+", "+requestId+", "+offset+")");
        Integer handle = mDeviceHandles.get(device);
        try {
            keepCallback(mCC, new JSONObject()
                .put("name", "read")
                .put("deviceHandle", handle)
                .put("requestId", requestId)
                .put("callbackHandle", mReadHandles.get(descriptor))
            );
        } catch(JSONException e) {
            throw new Error(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Bluetooth writing? Can you be more specific (codes maybe)? And what kind of Bluetooth hardware you are working on?

Comment: I am currently using phonegap(javascript) to work on BLE, i.e. cellphone communicate with BLE device. The reading/writing operation essentially bases on java based BLE plugin. Also, I want to generate tones on Android. What I am looking for is that is there a general way I can know the exact time between code execution and hardware responding?

Comment: how to post codes lol, I am new to stackoverfolow

Comment: Please post your code in your question directly, not in a comment.
Also, you'll need to expand on your question if you want to get some good answers. Is the hardware the underlying Android hardware? Or are you referring to a BLE peripheral device?

Comment: @ShuoLi there is an edit button below your question. Don't post codes in comments.

Comment: @SJoshi Thank you for your help, I specified my question and I posted the code, I hope this time u can understand my question

Comment: @Raptor I posted my code, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your example, but i'm currently working on android BLE too, but in Java.

In my case if i need to mesure latency time I'm used to get the current time in milliseconds before an operation. Then i retrive the current time after the operation.

The difference tells me how much did it take.

Hope I was helpful!

Comment: Thank you for your help, I specifed my question, also I posted the code. I want to know the exact time the hardware takes action, which is important to me.

Comment: I don't know how BLE works in phonegap and javascript, so I can't help you with code.

Comment: I think phonegap using javascript is not time accurate, so maybe I later I will switch to java, but is there a way in android OS that I can know the hardware responding time?

Comment: In Android java you can do it by System.currentTimeMillis();

Comment: Thank you. by the way, is it possible to go to very bottom layer of android OS so I can see where the OS access cellphone's hardware?

Comment: I don't think you can access such "low" layers. But if I where you i would implements all the avaiable callbacks and methods which are provided by BLE. Then I would measure the time between each call.

Comment: If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.